# Getting errors while running a function

Tags: c++, function

I'm getting some crazy errors while trying to use a function to find the median of a vector. I'm not exactly sure what's causing these errors.

1. 'Error 1 error C2601: 'calcMed' : local function definitions are illegal'

The function I'm trying to use is declared as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std; 

double calcMed(int, vector<int>& studentScores);

//

double homeworkMed = calcMed(vectorSize, studentScores);

double calcMed(int vectorSize, vector<int>& studentScores)
{
 double median;

  sort(studentScores.begin(), studentScores.end());

  median = studentScores[vectorSize / 2];

  return median;
}
```

I know that it wouldn't work if I had an odd vector but I just want to get this first one working. Any help would be appreciated.

Removed the semicolon on "double calcMed(int vectorSize, vector& studentScores)" and now I'm getting two different errors, both are on the line right after the function name.

Both of the errors occur on the line with the {

```
double calcMed(int vectorSize, vector<int>& studentScores)
{
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `calcAverage` involved? Give us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org), and I'll bet the problem will be obvious.

Comment: How does that compile unless you're trying to define it in `main`?

Comment: @chris it doesn't. CNR. =P

Comment: "Getting errors while running a function" - no, not quite. This is not a runtime error. This is a compilation error. You should at least have some idea as to what you are even doing.

Comment: @H2CO3 this is my first time using functions on C++, sorry for using incorrect words, I just know that if I comment out my function then my code runs without any errors, so I thought it was having issues running the function.

Comment: @user2781666 If you are just starting out with a language, and learning by trial and error, then it's inevitable to **do your own research.** These are basic (khm, ugh, trivial...) errors and solutions, and you should have googled the error messages instead of dumping them on Stack Overflow. To reiterate, Stack Overflow is not a website where we teach you a language -- you're expected to learn the basics yourself (there's [this excellent list of C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) around here, too, which may help you in the process).

Answer (score 2):

```
double calcMed(int vectorSize, vector<int>& studentScores);
{
  double median;

  sort(studentScores.begin(), studentScores.end());

  median = studentScores[vectorSize / 2];

  return median;
}
```

There shouldn't be a semicolon after the function signature in the definition. Change the first line to 
`double calcMed(int vectorSize, vector<int>& StudentScores)`

Comment: Thanks, I removed that and got two more errors on the { on the next line. I posted the new errors in the question

Comment: You can't define `calcMed` within `main()`. It should be declared and defined outside of `main()`.

Comment: I moved if before the 'main()' thanks. I still have the same errors though

Comment: Could you post the entirety of your code?

Comment: I'm hesitant to do that since it would make the question a lot more cluttered

Comment: In this case I believe it is the only way we will be able to help you fix the problem, so I encourage you to do it. I say this assuming your source isn't very long.

Comment: The total code is around 120 lines. I moved the function out of main() I had no idea why I put it inside, and now am down to just the one error

Comment: Please post it in its entirety.

Comment: @user2781666: You should not have written so much code before testing it.

Comment: @Beta How would you recommend writing code then? I'm mostly curious how you do it, I mostly start in the beginning (after making a plan in my head or in pseudo code) and then I work from the start to finish. This function takes a result that I go through several different loops to get all of the information for the code. Would you recommend doing a function, or at least setting it up, or something similar first then?

Comment: I would start with something small small and simple, like `HelloWorld`, *test it*, then add a function that returns 0, *test it*, then edit it to take a vector as an argument, *test it*, then edit it to print the vector, *test it*, then to sort it before printing it, *test it*, then to print the index it thinks is the middle one, *test it*, then to return the median, and finally remove the printout statements and *test it*, and above all I would **never add to code that doesn't work**. If you write from start to finish, it won't work at all until the end, so you can't test it, so it'll fail.

Answer (score 0):

The linker error is saying that it can't find an implementation of `calcAverage()`. Did you possibly rename `calcAverage()` to `calcMed()` and not update any calls to this function?

To fix this error, I would search all your code for `calcAverage()`, and either rename them to `calcMed()` or provide an implementation for it.

Comment: Sorry I changed the vector name after copying the codes, I updated the error

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out. For some reason I put the function inside my main(). After I moved it out of the brackets it solved the error. Thanks for everyone's help.